# ¿Como crear Inputs dinamicos con Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo un formulario para añadir muchos productos a una misma colección y quiero que en el formulario de crear coleccion pueda crear la colección con un lista ilimitada de productos.

Mi formulario es este:

```
class TendenciaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tendencia
        fields = ['nombre']

    producto = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Marca.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='producto-autocomplete')
    )
```

Sé que existen los formset pero están limitados a una cantidad y quiero que se puedan enviar todos los productos que necesiten de una misma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes encontrar mcha informacion en un articulo de Jacob Kaplan-Moss encontraras paso a paso y un claro ejemplo:
[dinamic forms](https://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/)